# Why is this C code executing half as fast when run via Python's ctypes than when run directly?

Tags: python, c

I'm playing around with Python-and-C interfacing, and as a simple test I was comparing the speed of a SuperFastHash implementation in C with one in Python, then looking at the result of just calling the C version from Python. This led to a surprising result. Here is the C code: http://pastebin.com/Hc7iqzH1 My benchmarking main() is at the bottom.

When compiling with `gcc -O3 -lrt hash_test.c` and running the executable, I get the following results: `secs: 20, hashes: 650449494, hashes/sec: 32522474.700000, Khashes/sec: 32522.474700`

When compiling a .so file with `gcc -lrt -O3 -fPIC -shared hash_test.c -o super.so`, and running a Python (2.7) script containing

```
from ctypes import *
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('./super.so')
lib.main()
```

I get the results: `secs: 20, hashes: 306842579, hashes/sec: 15342128.950000, Khashes/sec: 15342.128950`

This is only calculating about half as many hashes in the same amount of time as the direct program call. Why?

Comment: Try loading the `.so` file into a C driver program (with `dlopen()`, for example), and timing the calls. Executing position independent code has some penalty, but I don't know if it should be that bad.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That results in `secs: 20, hashes: 306993034, hashes/sec: 15349651.700000, Khashes/sec: 15349.651700`, so it's exhibiting the same slowdown. I knew that having PIC would have some performance penalty, but 50%? (I should also have mentioned I'm on x86_64.) Edit: Compiling a plain executable with -fPIC also exhibits the same slowdown, so I'm going to go with that as the cause.

Comment: As per como's answer, looks like just a simple case of inlining actually.

Comment: The PIC penalty is usually low, but it does involve an extra indirection per function invocation. Inlining would of course eliminate the indirection for the function pointer lookup.

Comment: I tested the PIC overhead for your hash function, and it is only 3.5% slower when invoked via PIC. Test methodology: move `main()` into a different source file from the hash function, so that in both cases (with PIC and without) it is a function call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for the performance draw back is that the compiler can not optimize as much in case of the shared library. It did not inline the call to SuperFastHash. But this is not related to the PIC format, as jxh suggested.

If you manually inline the call to SuperFastHash with the function code, you will see that the python code will yield the same performance as the original c code. Here is my version: https://gist.github.com/cod3monk/9821796

On the other hand, the bad performance from python can be reproduced using the following c code:

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

uint32_t SuperFastHash (const char * data, int len);

int main(void) {
      struct timespec start, end;
  long secs;
  long hashes = 0;
  char data[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20};
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
  clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
  while ((secs = end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) < 20) {
    uint32_t hash = SuperFastHash(data, 20);
    data[hash % 20] += 1;
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
    ++hashes;
  }

  printf("secs: %ld, hashes: %ld, hashes/sec: %f, Khashes/sec: %f\n", secs, hashes, hashes/20.0,
      hashes/20.0/1000.0);
  return 0;
}
```

and now compile with `gcc -O3 the_above_code.c super.so -lrt` and run it (`LD_LIBRARY_PATH=. ./a.out`).

Comment: A great answer! That said -- any chance the pastebin link could move to something less ad-laden? (gist.github.com, f'rinstance)

Comment: Since manually inlining is only copy and paste work, it would be easy to reproduce. And the original code is also at pastebin. I did not want to unnecessarily bloat my answer. Moved anyway ;)

Comment: Nice catch. The PIC being the slowdown did feel a little wrong... I also found that just by adding the 'inline' keyword to the function definition (not standard C89 but supported by gnu89) is enough to make gcc inline it.

Comment: Unfortunately the inline keyword is only a suggestion, in many cases the compiler will just ignore it completely. I used gcc-4.6.3 and ``inline'' did not gain me anything.